# QuerySet object has no attribute label Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Hi I am trying to render model form with some additional data sent from my view. But it is giving the following error when i try to access form with `form.as_p`:

> QuerySet' object has no attribute 'label'

test.html

```
<form action="." method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {{ form.as_p }}
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-5">
    {{form.tags}}
```

view.py

```
class ScheduledTestView(FormView):

serializer_class = TestShortSerializer

template_name = 'admin/scheduled_test.html'
form_class = ScheduledTestForm
initial = {'tags': Tag.objects.all()}


def form_valid(self, form):
    #some logic here
```

form.py

```
class ScheduledTestForm(forms.ModelForm):


    tags = forms.MultipleChoiceField(label='Tags', required=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.tags = kwargs['initial'].pop('tags', None)
        super(ScheduledTestForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['tags'] = self.tags

    class Meta:
        model = Test
```

error traceback

```
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
     'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'label'
Exception Location:                   /home/kishan/.virtualenvs/kishan_pal/local/lib/python3.4/site- packages/django/forms/forms.py in __init__, line 526
 Python Executable: /home/kishan/.virtualenvs/kishan_pal/bin/python
 Python Version:    3.4.0
```

Comment: Another approach to add field to model form .. from the view would also be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be setting the `choices` attribute of the field to the tags, what you're currently doing is changing the *value* of the field  from a [`MultipleChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#multiplechoicefield) to a `QuerySet`

So the following:

```
self.fields['tags']= self.tags
```

Should be:

```
self.fields['tags'].choices = self.tags
```

Comment: Thanks so much !! it worked . Now it says Tag object is not iterable error

Comment: @kishan - You may want to ask another question about that, make sure to include what you have tried/researched to solve that problem